# How do I convert an array of MKMapPoint values to a MKPolygon overlay

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a list of `MKMapPoint` values and I'd like to be able to convert these to a `MKPolygon` overlay. Is this possible?

`List<MKMapPoint> pointsList = new List<MKMapPoint>();`

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

`MKPolygon polygon = MKPolygon.FromPoints(pointsList);`

I get the error:

> **Error:** Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.List<MapKit.MKMapPoint>` to `MapKit.MKMapPoint[]`

Comment: The `poinstList` is a `List` of `MKMapPoint` objects and the `FromPoints` method takes an array. You need to convert the list to an array first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `List<MKMapMapPoint>` to an Array by using `ToArray()`:

`MKPolygon polygon = MKPolygon.FromPoints(pointsList.ToArray());`

Comment: can i do the opposite and pass the direct array in the method forit to work?

Comment: Yes, if you originally have an Array of MKMapPoint objects you can simply pass that Array to the method directly. Glad it worked.